# git grep results missing some files

Tags: git, grep, bitbucket

I'm working in a new repo, and I tried using `git grep` to find my way around. To my surprise, it seems to be missing results that normal `grep` finds:

```
igor.serebryany@breathy:~/repos/ansible {master} $ git grep argparse
igor.serebryany@breathy:~/repos/ansible {master} $ grep argparse *
inventory.py:import argparse
inventory.py:    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
igor.serebryany@breathy:~/repos/ansible {master} $
```

In fact, it seems like all files from a particular subdir of the repo are ignored by `git grep`.

I can't figure out why this would be the case. Is something wrong with the repo? Is there something I can do to fix it, or should I just avoid using `git grep` on this repo?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Turns out the file that's missing is a symlink to another repo that I also had checked out. If `git grep` is missing results that you expect, check to see if those files are actually symlinks!

Comment: That symlink is probably itself not a tracked file. By default, `git grep` ignores untracked files in the work-tree. Add `--untracked` to get it to look into such files (but if it's a symlink, it probably still won't follow the link to the target file—but I have not tested this).